# Spring batch to read CSV and update data in bulk to MySQL

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-batch

I've below requirement to write a spring batch. I would like to know the best approach to achieve it.

Input: A relatively large file with report data (for today)
Processing:
1. Update Daily table and monthly table based on the report data for today
Daily table - Just update the counts based on ID
Monthly table: Add today's count to the existing value

My concerns are:
1. since data is huge I may end up having multiple DB transactions. How can I do this operation in bulk?
2. To add to the existing counts of the monthly table, I must have the existing counts with me. I may have to maintain a map beforehand. But is this a good way to process in this way?

Please suggest the approach I should follow or any example if there is any?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can design a chunk-oriented step to first insert the daily data from the file to the table. When this step is finished, you can use a step execution listener and in the `afterStep` method, you will have a handle to the step execution where you can get the write count with `StepExecution#getWriteCount`. You can write this count to the monthly table.

> 1. since data is huge I may end up having multiple DB transactions. How can I do this operation in bulk?

With a chunk oriented step, data is already written in bulk (one transaction per chunk). This model works very well even if your input file is huge.

> 2. To add to the existing counts of the monthly table, I must have the existing counts with me. I may have to maintain a map beforehand. But is this a good way to process in this way?

No need to store the info in a map, you can get the write count from the step execution after the step as explained above.

Hope this helps.